# How do I detect end of file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, parsing, csv, eof

I wrote the following script to read a CSV file:

```
f = File.open("aFile.csv")
text = f.read
text.each_line do |line|
  if (f.eof?)
    puts "End of file reached"
  else
    line_num +=1
    if(line_num < 6) then
      puts "____SKIPPED LINE____"
      next
    end
  end

  arr = line.split(",")
  puts "line number  = #{line_num}" 
end
```

This code runs fine if I take out the line:

```
 if (f.eof?)
     puts "End of file reached"
```

With this line in I get an exception.

I was wondering how I can detect the end of file in the code above.

Comment: Side note: File inherits from IO; IO [has a lineno method](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/IO:lineno), no need for a counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/218093#946117 talks about this.

```
content = File.read("file.txt")
content = File.readlines("file.txt")
```

The above 'slurps' the entire file into memory.

```
File.foreach("file.txt") {|line| content << line}
```

You can also use [`IO#each_line`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-each_line).  These last two options do not read the entire file into memory.  The use of the block makes this automatically close your IO object as well.  There are other ways as well, IO and File classes are pretty feature rich!

I refer to IO objects, as File is a subclass of IO.  I tend to use IO when I don't really need the added methods from File class for the object.

In this way you don't need to deal with EOF, Ruby will for you.

Sometimes the best handling is not to, when you really don't need to.

Of course, Ruby has [a method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-eof-3F) for this.

Comment: The issue with `read` and `readlines` is they slurp the entire file into memory, which is only safe when you know the file will *always* fit into memory. `foreach` is always safe, and runs at nearly the same speed as slurping the entire file, so use `foreach` unless there are strong technical reasons to do otherwise, such as HAVING to have the entire file in a single string. `each_line` is the IO instance version of the IO class-method `foreach` so `IO.foreach` is equivalent to `File.foreach`.

Comment: Yes, indeed @theTinMan didn't think to bring that distinction up, I think it is mentioned in the documentation, or I just don't think about it any longer, consciously.  I will add the point in the answer, it is definitely a selling point.

Comment: It's also important for the OP to understand that it's idiomatic to use the block forms of IO and File methods to avoid the need to close files or check for EOF. It's just another way that Ruby makes programming more sane.

Comment: Already done. :) Looks like I was editing that in, while you were commenting about it.

Answer (score 7):

Try this short example:

```
f = File.open(__FILE__)
text = f.read
p f.eof?      # -> true
p text.class #-> String
```

With `f.read` you read the whole file into text and reach EOF.
(Remark: `__FILE__` is the script file itself. You may use you csv-file).

In your code you use `text.each_line`. This executes `each_line` for the string text. It has no effect on `f`.

You could use `File#each_line` without using a variable text. The test for EOF is not necessary. `each_line` loops on each line and detects EOF on its own.

```
f = File.open(__FILE__)
line_num = 0
f.each_line do |line|
  line_num +=1
  if (line_num < 6) 
     puts "____SKIPPED LINE____"
     next
  end

  arr = line.split(",")
  puts "line number  = #{line_num}" 
end
f.close
```

You should close the file after reading it. To use blocks for this is more Ruby-like:

```
line_num = 0
File.open(__FILE__) do | f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    line_num +=1
    if (line_num < 6) 
       puts "____SKIPPED LINE____"
       next
  end

    arr = line.split(",")
    puts "line number  = #{line_num}" 
  end
end
```

One general remark: There is a CSV library in Ruby. Normally it is better to use that.

Answer (score 1):

Without testing this, it seems you should perform a rescue rather than checking.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/EOFError.html

```
file = File.open("aFile.csv")

begin
  loop do
    some_line = file.readline
    # some stuff
  end
rescue EOFError
  # You've reached the end. Handle it.
end
```

Comment: Performing a rescue for an EOF is not necessarily the best tactic, as it is not exceptional behavior to find an `eof` at the end of a file.  And exceptions should be reserved for exceptional behavior, behavior that probably shouldn't happen, or if it does, it wasn't expected to in the normal flow of things.